# If "heimal" means "hey", what does "hei-dee" mean?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, single-word-request

Heimal translates to "hey", but I similarly heard "hei-Dee" from the same person. The translator fails to give its english meaning. I don't think it's to be mistaken with the Swiss name "Heidi" which instead has emphasis on the first syllable instead of the second. Or I might have misheard, and it is just the same as saying the name. what does this expression mean?

Comment: *heimal* and *hei-Dee* are extremely uncommon - could you please give more context? Who uses this? Is this from a movie or similar? Is the speaker from a certain time period or region?

Comment: it was said by a European person not native to Germany or switzerland  in present day

Comment: Could it be from an other language than German? And what exactly is the person saying? In which situation?

Comment: I'm not quite sure from the question whether "Dee" is meant to be pronounced as English or German; the English pronunciation would be spelled *di* or *die* in German, and the German pronunciation would be something like "day" in English. I think it's good practice to everything in German (or language other  than English) in *italics*, unless the post is in German in which case put English in italics.

Answer (score 1):

Neither *»heimal«* nor *»hei-dee«* are German words. They are not used by German native speakers and have no meaning.

---

The most common German translations for the English salutation *»Hey!«* is:

> Hallo!

Also in use:

> He!
> Hey!

---

The female surname *»Heidi«* is not Swiss ("Swiss" is not a language, similar to »Canadian« not being a language.) *»Heidi«* is the short version of *»Adelheid«* which is a German given name.

*Heidi Klum* is a German top-model, *Heidi Horton* is an Austrian Billionaire, *Heidi Preuss* is an US-American alpine skier, *Heidi Greni* is a Norwegian politician, and *Heidi Range* is a British pop singer.

Comment: In the US it's possible to say "Canadian" for "Canadian English". (The difference between US and Canadian English small but very noticeable to native speakers.) My understanding is that while the Swiss do learn Standard German in school, they do have a distinct dialect which is called Swiss German. Maybe you have to be more careful in German but I think in English you can get away with calling it Swiss for short. The suffix *-i* is (according to Wiktionary) common, and perhaps this is an instance of it. I've heard/read *Hallöchen" so there is a precedent.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast I think you meant Adelheid was a German *given* name and thus corrected it.

Comment: There are given names which are typical for Switzerland (like *Beat*) but *Heidi* is not one of them.

Comment: I think the reasoning surrounding "Swiss" is a bit odd. Names can originate from or be associated with a place, and that can be expressed by the adjective based on that place, even if that adjective does not denote a language at the same time. As such, a name can be "Swiss" (schweizerisch) even if anything related to the *language* spoken in Switzerland would be referred to as "Swiss German" (schweizerdeutsch).

Comment: @RDBury: People in Canada also speak French. So, *Canadian* should mean both, English and French. (And *Swiss* should mean German and French and Italian and Romansh.)

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast: Yes, you would think that we'd be for logical about this, seeing as we're so logical about everything else :) But when which I think of a Canadian accent it's Canadian English, not a *Québécois* accent or the accent of one of the indigenous languages. There are people who confuse language with nationality and might say something like "Sorry, I don't speak Mexican." But it's better to give people the benefit of the doubt on this kind of thing when possible.